# Format timespan to have zero before hour and minute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i add zero before hour or min in VS2012.

I an converting seconds into hours and minutes. Here is my code to cope with hours > 24

```
 Dim x As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 96000)
 MsgBox(String.Format("{0}hr:{1}min", CInt(Math.Truncate(x.TotalHours)), x.Minutes))
```

It is working fine and i get following results:

```
26hr:40min
```

If seconds are 3600 then i get  1hr:0min, is there any way to have it in following format:

```
01hr:00min
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to have it in following format: 01hr:00min

Yes, you can use `{0:00}` in the format string. The first zero is the index of the argument(as usual in `String.Format`), the other two  zeros are placeholders:

```
String.Format("{0:00}hr:{1:00}min", CInt(x.TotalHours), x.Minutes)
```

Documentation: [The "0" Custom Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx#Specifier0)

Comment: you mean String.Format("{0:00}hr:{1:00}min", CInt(x.TotalHours), x.Minutes)